# How to add dsiddharth2/php-zxing library into Laravel project

Tags: php, laravel, barcode, zxing, decoder

I have installed `dsiddharth2/php-zxing` into laravel project.

After that, I write sample **code:**

```
<?php

use PHPZxing\PHPZxingDecoder;

  $decoder = new PHPZxingDecoder();
  $data = $decoder->decode('https://internationalbarcodes.com/wp-content/uploads/sites/95/2013/09/07-EAN-13-Standard-1.jpg');

  if($data instanceof PHPZxing\ZxingImage) {
     print_r($data);
  }
?>
```

And it gives **error:**

> File/Folder does not exist.

Can you please help how can I add above library into laravel project.

Comment: Do you  have Java and the Zxing library installed?

Comment: I think yes, installed via composer. https://github.com/dsiddharth2/php-zxing

Comment: Not sure if this is enough. From that page: "_Under the hood it still uses the Zxing library to encode and decode data._" I guess you'd need to install https://github.com/zxing/zxing for it to work.

Comment: As per document it is used for android, while I need php library https://github.com/dsiddharth2/php-zxing

Comment: Or how can I create module of https://github.com/dsiddharth2/php-zxing code into laravel??